# The Ultimate edition for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I currently have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition, so I was searching for the Ultimate edition for Visual Studio 2017, but I don't find it for download. The [Compare Visual Studio 2017 Offerings](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) or [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) lists only Community, Professional and Enterprise editions.

I logged into my MSDN subscription and don't find it there either.

What happened to the Ultimate edition? Where can I download it from?

Comment: There is no Ultimate edition.  They consolidated the number of SKUs starting with VS 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the Visual Studio 2017 licensing whitepaper](https://www.visualstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Visual-Studio-2017-Licensing-Whitepaper-March-2017.pdf), and how subscription transitions from 2015 to 2017 are handled, it sounds like the equivalent 2017 version of Visual Studio to the one you want is Enterprise.